# SlideDown/Up doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I'm not the best in jQuery (also not english), but I want to learn it. So, I wanted to make a slideUp and slideDown button. But it just do "slideDown".

```
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
    $(".shownDesc").slideUp("slow", function () {
        removeClass(".shownDesc") 
        });

    $(".showDIV").slideDown("slow", function () {
        addClass(".shownDesc")
        });
    });
```

.toggle is my content DIV and "showDIV" is my inner.

It should be open "showDIV" when I press the ".toggle"-Class. But it doesn't want slideUp the "showDIV"-Element.

```
    <div class="toggle">Show text!</div>
    <div class="showBack">
      Normal text.
    </div>  

    <div class="toggle">Show other text!</div>
    <div class="showBack">
        Other text.
    </div>
```

Maybe you will need this HTML code ;)

Comment: You don't have any div that has the shownDesc or showDIV class, that's why it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will make the two pieces of text toggle when you click on the .toggle object on your HTML.  There is no need to add/remove classes:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".showBack").slideToggle();
});
```

This uses the slideToggle() method which automatically does a slideUp or slideDown depending upon the previous state.

It also automatically finds the next item (with the .showBack class) after the .toggle class and applies the slide operation to that element.

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/z9Afs/

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery .slideToggle might be the better option in this case.

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Example:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $(".showDIV").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

I may need some further explanation in order to exactly write the code for you.